# Is it possible to do gradle release and debug builds in non-Android project?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I'm building a REST Client Api that will be now used in a desktop java application as well as an Android app. With the android gradle plugin, you can specify buildConfigFields in buildTypes for server urls so the debug build would point to test server and release build would point to production server

How can I accomplish this without using the android gradle plugin?
I only know the basics in Gradle but could this be accomplished easily with a gradle task?

Comment: Have you consulted the gradle documentation?

Comment: Yes, if I missed something-can you post the link please