# How to use build variants in a non-android project?

Tags: java, android, gradle, kotlin

I have a backend system that connects to a database. During development I'd like to provide an in-memory persistence implementation that doesn't require a running database. In Android projects we can use build variants to have different binaries for different environments. This would allow me to build a jar for development purposes and one release jar.

**Is there something similar for non-android projects?**

There have been [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44050420/is-it-possible-to-do-gradle-release-and-debug-builds-in-non-android-project) before but none of them provide up-to-date solutions. Please note that I do not want my final jar to contain the development implementation so a runtime switch is not an option.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40659986/maven-profiles-equivalent-of-gradle) should help.

Comment: @AndrewS thanks! That should work indeed but maybe there are ways that are supported by the IDE (like build variants). Additionally it requires that I have modules that I can include or exclude, unlike build variants.